# Check particular process in loop for every 5 min for 30 min

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ksh

Hello I have requirement where during intial server provision I have to execute this shell script.
I need to check for agent (ps -ef|grep agent) for every 5 min..if agent is installed I need to run /home/usr/job.ksh and exit the script.
If agent is not installed for 30 min than I need to put message 'agent not installed' and exit.

Please help in logic for this shell script.

Comment: `help in logic` - you have just written and exaplined the whole logic of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
for _ in {1..6}                         # Run loop for 6 times (6*300=1800s ~ 30min)
do
    if [ $(ps -ef|grep agent|egrep -v grep|wc -l) -ge 1 ]
    then
        /home/usr/job.ksh
        exit 0
    else
        sleep 300                       # Sleep for 5min
    fi
done
echo "agent not installed"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you see 'flock' command?

```
flock -w10 /var/tmp/job.lock /home/usr/job.ksh
```

-w10 - 10 sec wait before try start if not started (change for 30 min if need)

And add this string to /etc/crontab for every 5 min:

```
*/5 * * * * root /bin/ksh /home/usr/job.ksh
```

Comment: Thank you Serg. Actually the above requirement is of one time use for each server getting provisioned. Wait for the agent to get installed for 30 min if not installed the script should exit as failed . I need to check in between if agent is installed for every 5 min. 
Regards,
Amith

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for _ in {1..180}; do
    if pgrep agent &>/dev/null; then
        /home/usr/job.ksh
        exit
    fi
    sleep 10
done
echo "agent not intalled"
```

Run loop 180 times and check if agent is running. Between the checks sleep for 10 seconds.